# Just Upgraded to iPhone SDK 4.2(Xcode 3.2.5) and No Longer Have Some Framerworks

Tags: frameworks, ios4, linker-errors

I just upgraded to the latest Xcode version(3.2.5) and attempted to build and run my code that ran and compiled just fine in SDK 4.1, but am getting linker errors and have realized this is due to the frameworks apparently not being found in the project. When I right click, and select Add... Existing Frameworks, some frameworks like MapKit, UIKit, and CoreGraphics aren't found in the list that allows you to choose from. Any ideas of what happened and what I can do to fix this? I was thinking of going into Finder and dragging the frameworks in, however there are many directories of the same framework when I do a search for one of them in Spotlight. Any feedback appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it turns out I needed to set my project's settings to use the latest SDK(it was still using 4.1).